# Default selected value ion ion-radio that have dynamic values using reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

i'm using ion-radio , that have dynamic value, and need to set the first value as selected using reactive form.

```
 <ion-list radio-group formControlName="typeName">
                <ion-label class="label-radio">
                  Type
                </ion-label>
                <ion-item *ngFor="let option of options">
                  <ion-label>{{option.name}}</ion-label>
                  <ion-radio [value]="option.id"></ion-radio>
                </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

typescript:

```
constructor(...){
 this.excavationInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
     ...
     **IntersectionType: '',**
     ...

    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code where you create the form control?

Comment: @sebaferreras see the updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the value of that control when crating it, to be the id of the first option to make it selected by default:

```
this.excavationInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
  // ...
  typeName: [options[0].id],
  // ...
});
```

**EDIT:**

If the data is not available by that time, you can initialize it as empty

```
this.excavationInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
  // ...
  typeName: [''],
  // ...
});
```

And then when the list of options is ready, update the value of the control:

```
this.excavationInformationForm.get('typeName').setValue(options[0].id);
```

Comment: i can't do that because the data coming from the server, and when the constructor do his job, the data will not be available .

Comment: i think no need to null i put it as empty string '' , and the rest same as you said, thanks, it works

Comment: You're absolutely right, I've updated the answer with your comment. Thanks a lot for pointing that out :)